# Amplify Authenticator displaying unwanted greeting

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

I am using the aws Authenticator in my React app.  I chose to use this instead of withAuthenticator as I want users to be able to visit my site without being forced to login first.  My understanding is that by using the standard Authenticator component, the greetings (signout button/navbar) does not appear.  I need to implement that myself.  Fine.  Unfortunately, even just using the Authenticator, not using withAuthenticator,  I am still getting that signout button appearing, which I do not want.

Below is my code.  Any ideas as to why this signout button continues to plague me?

````
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import { Authenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Hub.listen("auth", data => {
      switch (data.payload.event) {
        case "signIn":
          console.log("signed in");
          this.props.authentication.setAuthState("signedIn");
          this.props.authentication.getUserData();
          break;
        case "signOut":
          console.log("signed out");
          this.props.authentication.setAuthState("signedOut");
          break;
        case "signIn_failure":
          this.setState({
            authState: "signIn",
            authData: null,
            authError: data.payload.data
          });
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
    this.state = {
      authState: null
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login">
        <Authenticator />
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default Login;```
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem on my own, though I am not sure if it should have been necessary.  In my Authenticator component I used the `hide ={[Greetings]}` option.  (note that you need to import Greetings along with Authenticator to do this.  My assumption was that by default, the Authenticator component does not display the greeting on its own; that this was part of the withAuthenticator HOC, and therefor the step I took should not have been necessary.  If anyone knows why I had to do this then I would like to learn.
Mahalo